# Software that adds a real-time watermark to an online screencast

Tags: video, screencasts, watermark, teamviewer

I use TeamViewer for remote presentation. Is there any software that would allow adding a real-time watermark with my company logo/name on screen?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [Screen Watermark](http://screenwatermark.sourceforge.net/) should be able to do the thing that you're looking for. It's available in binary form only for Win64, but source code is available and it's Qt-based so should compile and run on most platforms. Here's an overview from their (sparse) documentation:

> Screen Watermark is an application that overlays an image over the desktop
>   and can act as a flexible watermark on videos or pictures taken
>   directly off the screen. The main use is for adding in a watermark
>   when your video or screen capture software does not support watermarks
>   correctly or at all.
>
> Configuration file is config.xml
>       You can change the default starting position.
>
> Key Bindings: W: one pixel up S: one pixel down A: one pixel left D:
>   one pixel right
>
> TGFH: ten pixels IKJL: twenty pixels
>
> N: 10% more translucent M: 10% less translucent
>
> X: Exit

Call it with your watermark picture's filename as argument.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! When answering questions, solely recommending software is discouraged.  If a part of your solution involves the use of a particular piece of software, I would consider using this [meta post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) as a guideline.

Comment: Thanks @KronoS. I'll try to make myself more familiar with the guidelines.